# Google+ and Facebook Login on Page Load

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am successful in implementing Facebook API and Google+ API. I don't haven any issues with login or logout.  Even when page is refreshed information is working fine.

But when user logs into Google+ and Facebook in different tabs and he provided access to the app by login with both accounts then I am seeing both images.

How can I avoid this. On page load, I would like to see only either Facebook or Google+ but not both.

- If Facebook login then show only Facebook
- If Google+ Login then show only Google
- If he is logged in to both then show only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just out, how to do both:

One of the key parts is the concept of identities vs users. A user represents a human, an identity represents a human logging in with a particular social network. Data security is done on users, showing photos and whatnot is done on identities.

The first code snippet shows some pretty simple logic for deciding which login provider to use if a user is logged in with both.

https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices/facebook#separating_social_and_business_logic

Answer (score 0):

Only allow them to associate their Google+ or Facebook accounts, not both. If one is associated, then do not allow the other.